# Angular2 - how to display data that arrives later

Tags: angular

Oh dear angular2 why oh why....

My git_list array arrives later.  Why the error when I use async?  If I dont use async then when the data arrives data is not displayed.

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./GitaccountsComponent class GitaccountsComponent - inline template:26:17 caused by: Invalid argument '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
Error: Invalid argument '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

<md-grid-tile *ngFor="let item of git_list  | async" [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">


</md-grid-tile>




 git_list = [
  {
    "git_account": "gggggggggg",
    "git_host": "bitbucket"
  },
  {
    "git_account": "yiofysdgsdgfs",
    "git_host": "bitbucket"
  },
  {
    "git_account": "yyyyyyyy",
    "git_host": "bitbucket"
  },
  {
    "git_account": "TTTTT",
    "git_host": "github"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you add the assignment line of `git_list` in your ts/js?

Comment: Have you tried adding an ngIf, i.e. `<md-grid-tile *ngIf="git_list  | async">`?

Comment: `| async` is not for data that arrives later, it's only for data of type `Observable` or `Promise`. If `git_list` is not an `Observable` or `Promise`, `| async` can't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a `*ngIf` and it should work, so data will be placed when it arrives and not throw an error. You would have to make e.g an extra div here, as two directives cannot be placed in one tag, and you already have and `*ngFor` in your `md-grid-tile`, I would just add an extra div like so:

```
<div *ngIf="git_list" >
   <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let item of git_list" [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
     <!-- Your code here --->
   </md-grid-tile>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!